# Sonarqube issue: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to parse entry in bootstrap index - is also removing plugin auth aad

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, sonarqube, devops

We have sonarqube hosted on azure container app.
We have pipeline configured on azure Devops, this is throwing some intermittent errors(Does not happen all the time), when it happens, it is also removing the authadd plugin. I can see that plugin is present in db but it no longer shows on login page and need to be installed again.
We are on 8.9.2

Here are the configuration on azure(some values have been changed for security reasons)

```
[
{
“name”: “DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD”,
“value”: “ ",
“slotSetting”: false
},
{
“name”: “DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL”,
“value”: “https://registery.azurecr.io”,
“slotSetting”: false
},
{
“name”: “DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME”,
“value”: “Registery”,
“slotSetting”: false
},
{
“name”: “PORT”,
“value”: “9000”,
“slotSetting”: false
},
{
“name”: “SONAR.JDBC.URL”,
“value”: “jdbc:sqlserver://db.database.windows.net:1433;database=project_sonarqube”,
“slotSetting”: false
},
{
“name”: “SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME”,
“value”: “dev”,
“slotSetting”: false
},
{
“name”: “SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD”,
“value”: " **”,
“slotSetting”: false
},
{
“name”: “WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE”,
“value”: “false”,
“slotSetting”: false
}
]
```

---

### [Raised issue on SonarQube which has related logs](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/caused-by-java-lang-illegalstateexception-fail-to-parse-entry-in-bootstrap-index-is-also-removing-plugin-auth-aad/53879)

Pipeline

Tasks on Azure pipeline
pool:

vmImage: ‘ubuntu-20.04’

variables:

solution: ‘**/*.sln’

buildPlatform: ‘Any CPU’

buildConfiguration: ‘prod’

task: SonarQubePrepare@4
task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
displayName: Restore
task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
displayName: Build
task: SonarQubeAnalyze@4

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below can be of use in your case:

1. It is optional for latest version  but try to pass
   Dsonar.es.bootstrap.checks.disable=”$SONAR_ES_BOOTSTRAP_CHECKS_DISABLE”.

   Set the environment variables

```js
 SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL = 
SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD = SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME =
SONAR_ES_BOOTSTRAP_CHECKS_DISABLE = true
WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT = 400
```

(Optional this is to
override default wait time limit of container start)  Reference:
[Hosting SonarQube](https://shubhamgargcth.github.io/SonarQubeAzureAppService/)

2. As you said the error occurs sometimes only ,this may not be the
   case but just check if error may occur due to incorrect url .Please
   check the spaces after the slash at the end.
3. If 1.1 RC2 or newer of the aad auth plugin , you will need to make a
   manual query to create a unique value.check the latest
   [Upgrades](https://github.com/hkamel/sonar-auth-aad/wiki/Upgrading).
4. A SonarQube service restart is essential to enable the plugin after the installation of aad auth plgin. And at the same time Set up the Server base URL to be configured with HTTPS address in Administration >>Configuration >> General >> Server base URL and redirect url in azure ad  must be "`https://sonarqube.example.com/oauth2/callback/aad`". If `https://sonarqube.example.com` is server url
5. Check this [blog](https://www.cloudmanav.com/azure/deploying-sonarqube-azure-container/) and also check the set up of host url by checking according to the proxy settings.

References:

1. [sonar-auth-aad Wiki (github.com)](https://github.com/hkamel/sonar-auth-aad/wiki/Setup)
2. [SonarQube Integration with Azure Active Directory (emtec.digital)](https://www.emtec.digital/think-hub/blogs/sonarqube-integration-azure-active-directory/)
3. [Running SonarQube behind an IIS Reversed Proxy | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/visualstudioalmrangers/running-sonarqube-behind-an-iis-reversed-proxy)

Else you may raise  a support request from overview page of azure ad portal>troubleshooting > raise a support request